# Minimal awaitable example

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++-coroutine, boost-coroutine

I wonder why the following programme crashes. How to use `awaitable` not with `boost::asio::async_write`/`async_read` functions.

Let's see:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>

using boost::asio::io_context;
using boost::asio::co_spawn;
using boost::asio::awaitable;
using boost::asio::detached;

awaitable<void> task() {
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  return awaitable<void>{};
}

int main() {
  try {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context(1);

    co_spawn(io_context, task(), detached);

    io_context.run();
  } catch(const std::exception &ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
hello
(Segmentation fault)
```

What is wrong about it?

***UPD***: self-solved.
I should just use `co_return`. Thus it must be the following:

```
awaitable<void> task() {
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  co_return;
}
```

Comment: There is no C++20 coroutine being employed here.

Comment: In your debugger, where does the crash happen?

Comment: @alterigel inside the `push_frame` function within `awaitable.hpp` at the first line where it tries to `caller_ = caller`.

Comment: solution found: just use `c++20` keyword 'co_return' instead of 'return awaitable<void>{}';

Comment: In `co_spawn(io_context, task(), detached);` you are calling `task` and passing it's return value to the function. I'm guessing that's not intended.

Comment: @super, they say, if you are not aware of the topic it is better not to vent ... To wrap up, it is correct. More, the problem is already solved, just read the asnwer below.

Comment: @dronte7 The fact that something compiles doesn't make it correct. Your example code is in direct contrast with the [example here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutines_ts.html) for the very reason I pointed out, for example. With that said, it was just an attempt to maybe be helpful. No need for the condescending reply.

Comment: @super, Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude, really sorry. Now, I see that you are correct as well. Thank you for pointing that out, with the link it is much more clear. Previously, I have seen only the overload of `co_spawn` which requires an `awaitable` object. The opportunity to pass just a function was missed. Thank you!

P.S. example proving that my variant is correct as well: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

digging into the sources of `boost::asio::awaitable`, I figured out that I just should make use of `co_return` keyword. Surprisingly, it is **not** shipped with `boost`. It is enabled either by `-fcoroutines` flag or `-std=c++20`. Unexpectedly. Having said that, it is solved.